# Passing multiple JSON values in CURL

Tags: php, json, curl

I have a curl request like the following :

```
curl -d 'api_user=your_sendgrid_username&api_key=your_sendgrid_password&list=my_list&data[]={"email":"address1@domain.com","name":"contactName1"}&data[]={"email":"address2@domain.com","name":"contactName2"}' https://sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/add.json
```

Now I am using the following php code for the post

```
if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    $data = array();
    while($new_signups = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $data['email'] = $new_signups['uEmail'];
        $data['name'] = $new_signups['firstName']." ".$new_signups['lastName'];
    }
}
$params = array(
    'api_user'  => $sengrid_user,
    'api_key'   => $sendgrid_pass,
    'list' =>'TestAlwin',
    'data' =>json_encode($data)
  );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $request);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But this will only take care of the last result. How can I pass more data values as given in the curl request above ? Or I need to run the curl transfer in the loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a multidimensional array of the data. Each array value contains another array with the email and name data:

```
$c=1;
while($new_signups = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){

    $data[$c]['email'] = $new_signups['uEmail'];
    $data[$c]['name'] = $new_signups['firstName']." ".$new_signups['lastName'];
    $c++;

}
```

So your data would be something like:

```
array(
   1 => array(
      'email' => 'test@test.nl',
      'name' => 'John'

   ),
   2 => array(
      'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
      'name' => 'Jack'

   ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your data array always try this

```
//multiple array
$data1 = array()


if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {

    while($new_signups = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $data = array();
        $data['email'] = $new_signups['uEmail'];
        $data['name'] = $new_signups['firstName']." ".$new_signups['lastName'];
    //bind your single array here
    $data1[] = $data;
    }
}
$params = array(
    'api_user'  => $sengrid_user,
    'api_key'   => $sendgrid_pass,
    'list' =>'TestAlwin',
    'data' =>json_encode($data1)
  );
```